# Schwarz's lemma, conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}-\{a\}$ and that $a$ is a pole of order $m$ of $f$. Suppose that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$, $|f(z)|\leq 1$, prove that for all $z\in\mathbb{D}-\{a\}$, $$|f(z)|\leq \biggl\lvert\frac{1-\bar{a}z}{z-a}\biggr\rvert^m$$

I know that if $a$ is a pole of $f$ of order m, then $f$ can be written as $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^m}$ in which $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ and $g(a)\neq 0$. I think we need to use Schwarz lemma and the conformal self map on unit disk. But I have no idea how to put them together.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The function $g(z)= \left (\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right)^mf(z)$ is holomorphic on $\overline {\mathbb D}.$ How large is $|g|$ on the unit circle?

Comment: $|g|\leq 1$ on the unit circle, so it immediately gives the result by using maximal principle. Thank you!